# How to filter a NetCDF dataset with xarray.sel() by specific month in time component?

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-science, netcdf, python-xarray

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

data = xr.open_dataset("Phytoplankton.nc")

darmstadt = data.phyc.sel(latitude=26,longitude=-90)
darmstadt.plot()
```

And here is the time array:

```
array(['2000-01-16T12:00:00.000000000', '2000-02-15T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2000-03-16T12:00:00.000000000', ..., '2018-10-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-11-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-12-16T12:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I want to filter `darmstadt` in such a way that only januaries that is `-01-` would be represented.

Answer (score 1):

I find that simply grouping the time dimension by month does the work.

```
data2 = data.groupby('time.month').sum(dim='time')
darmstadt = data2.phyc.sel(latitude=26,longitude=-90).sel(month=1)
```